# Parse "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" to LocalDateTime in Kotlin by using annotation

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I want to parse String with template "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" to `LocalDateTime` by using Annotation.

I tried to parse through below code but it throws me an error.
What should I do for fixing this error?

Code:

```
SearchREQ(
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    var departureDate: LocalDateTime,
)
```

Error:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime];
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
  Cannot construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime (no Creators,
      like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory
      method to deserialize from String value ('2018-08-20T06:00:00')
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 22]
  (through reference chain: gtd.connector.model.req.SearchREQ[\"departureDate\"])
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: What is the error?  I ask, because reading through it might help to tip you off as to what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDateTime` has no `String` constructors. A possible workaround would be this:

```
class SearchREQ(
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    var departureDate: Date
) {
  val departureDateTime get() =  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(departureDate.toInstant(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC").toZoneId())!!
}
```

You can also implement a custom deserializer for `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: I prefer your idea to implement a custom deserializer for LocalDateTime, as that would avoid having to deal with the outdated Date class.